# Solution of Laplace equation with linear and homogeneous boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In section 2.9 of Batchelor's 'An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics', the author seeks to solve $\nabla^2\phi = 0$, where $\phi$ is a function of $x, y, z$, subject to the boundary conditions (a) $\phi \rightarrow$ constant as $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \rightarrow \infty$ and (b) $\hat{n}\cdot\nabla\phi = \hat{n}\cdot\vec{U}$, where $\vec{U}$ is a constant vector. $\vec{U}$ is the translational velocity of a rigid body moving through a fluid which is at rest at infinity.

He later writes that because the differential equation and the boundary conditions are linear and homogeneous, the solution is of the form $\phi(\vec{x}) = \vec{U}\cdot\vec{\Phi}(\vec{x})$. I need help in understanding how the author concludes that this form is appropriate.